# Is there a way to serve allure reports from python script?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, allure

I have an endpoint which when hit, runs `pytest.main()` command in my repo and runs all pytest cases.

Now I want to generate allure reports and serve them on a specific host. I want this to happen via a python script is there a way to do this?

I could achieve this by executing CLI arguments via python script but that solution seemed like a hack. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import subprocess

def generate():
"""
Run command to set allure path and generate allure report after the test run is over
"""
#stores report in raw format ( .txt and .json) in this location
reports = os.getcwd()+'/reports'
#stores processed reports int html format in this location
reportserver = os.getcwd()+'/reportserver'

command_generate_allure_report = ['allure generate '+reports+' -o '+reportserver+' --clean']
subprocess.call(command_generate_allure_report, shell=True)
```

Once this is executed formatted reports will be stored in the location